# Show all rows in MySQL that contain the same value (specific value)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have MYSQL database

```
id | value1 | value2
---+--------+-------
1  |    1   |   1
2  |   10   |   3
3  |   10   |   3
4  |   10   |   2
5  |   11   |   3
6  |   11   |   2
7  |   12   |   1
8  |   13   |   4
```

How would I return a list of all the columns where the same value1 appears more than once but specific value, eg, I'd like to return with value1 = 10:

```
value1 | value2
  10   |   3
  10   |   3
  10   |   2
```

I have use count query like this:

`SELECT value1,value2 FROM table WHERE value1 in (
     SELECT value1 FROM table GROUP BY value1=10 having count(*) > 1 )`

but the return like this

```
value1 | value2
   1   |   1
  10   |   3
  10   |   3
  10   |   2
```

why return come with value1=1 ?

any idea? thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning that row with value1 = 1 because of the

```
GROUP BY value1=10
```

That's specifying grouping by the result of a boolean expression, which returns 1 (TRUE), 0 (FALSE) or NULL for each row.

To get the count of rows that have the same value for value1, you'd want

```
GROUP BY value1
```

If you only want to return rows where value1 is equal to 10, you could include a predicate in a WHERE clause

```
WHERE value1 = 10
```

---

If I were going to return the specified result set, I'd do it with a query something like this:

```
SELECT t.value1
     , t.value2
  FROM ( SELECT r.value1
           FROM table r
          WHERE r.value1 = 10
          GROUP BY r.value1
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) s
  JOIN table t
    ON t.value1 = s.value1
```

If I wanted to use a subquery in a predicate (instead of a join operation) I could do something like this:

```
SELECT t.value1, t.value2
  FROM tableX t
 WHERE t.value1 = 10
   AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableX r WHERE r.value1 = 10) > 1
```

The previous query with join pattern can easily be extended to return multiple values, we could replace the `WHERE r.value = 10` with `WHERE r.value IN (10,20,30)`. With the second query, with the subquery in the predicate, that can't be as easily extended, not without a (potentially) light dimming correlated subquery.

Comment: I would add a `WHERE t.value1 = 10` as well.

Comment: @ypercube: yes, we could add that predicate. (it might improve performance if value1 is a leading column in an index), but it wouldn't change the result returned.

Comment: all the code work well. I use the simple code, because easy to implement. thanks u all. sorry for my bad english. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
SELECT value1,value2 FROM table WHERE value1 in (
     SELECT value1 FROM table where value1 = 10) and (select count(*) where value1 = 10)>1

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where value1=10
        )>1
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5